# My Pixel 1 XL keeps asking to sign in to my WiFi router

Tags: wifi-hotspot, google-pixel, android-10

My phone keeps asking me to sign into my WiFi router. Almost every morning, same goes for my wife's Pixel 1 XL. Is this a phone issue or router issue? Forgetting the network doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: Do you get redirected to a router page? If yes, on the 3 dots menu you have two options, forget network and use the network as it is. Select second option. IMO it is a router issue and I invariably have this problem when on VPN and away from router but not a problem once connected as described

Comment: I don't get redirected. https://imgur.com/a/UU6XpSa I just notice my WiFi isn't authenticated or something. I have to go into the WiFi menu (long press) and click to sign on. The problem persists even if I forget the network.

Comment: I am on Android 10. I get exactly the same icon. Instead of going to settings when I long press the wifi icon a corresponding page opens up in Chrome with options as described.

Comment: Check your browser if such a page appears

Comment: I'm using Firefox preview, but my wife uses chrome. I'll see what happens next time it happens.

Comment: Looks like your WiFi router provides a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)? Then looks like it is a router configuration, which is more on-topic on [su].

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll post over there.

Comment: I don't ever get redirected to a log in page.